# Tkinter Radiobutton fills multiple rows when using widget.grid()

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, row

I'm having some trouble properly gridding these Radio Buttons alongside other widgets. The Radio buttons never go into the row specified, sometimes being placed in the middle of several rows.

I'm trying to get Radio buttons "One" and "Two" in line with Buttons "Quit1" and "Quit2".

```
from Tkinter import *

class myFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.grid()
        v = IntVar()

        r1 = Radiobutton(self.parent, text="One", variable=v, value=1)
        r2 = Radiobutton(self.parent, text="Two", variable=v, value=2)
        quit1 = Button(self, text = "quit1", command = self.master.destroy)
        quit2 = Button(self, text = "quit2", command = self.master.destroy)
        quit3 = Button(self, text = "quit3", command = self.master.destroy)

        quit1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        quit2.grid(row=1, column=0)
        quit3.grid(row=2, column=0)
        r1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        r2.grid(row=1, column=1)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = myFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the parent widget of your *Radiobuttons* is different from the parent widget of your *Buttons*.

Just change the following 2 lines:

```
r1 = Radiobutton(self.parent, text="One", variable=v, value=1)
r2 = Radiobutton(self.parent, text="Two", variable=v, value=2)
```

To:

```
r1 = Radiobutton(self, text="One", variable=v, value=1)
r2 = Radiobutton(self, text="Two", variable=v, value=2)
```

Keep in mind also that widget stretch enough to make space for them selves, and that's it.

Comment: Perfect. Question, though: If the Radiobuttons' master was the root Tk() instance, and the Buttons' master was the Frame instance, how were they working together with the grid system at all? The Radiobuttons' positions shouldn't have been influenced by the presence of the Buttons.

Comment: A `Frame` has its own grid system and also the instance of `Tk`. Think about it like if it was a grid inside another grid, or a table inside another table.  The first parameter passed to a widget is its parent widget. When you grid or pack a widget, it's referred to its parent widget. Your example could work perfectly. You grid a Frame and Radiobuttons in a Tk instance at the same time.